# Creating filters for javafx tablecolumns

Tags: java, swing, filter, javafx-2, tablecolumn

I am working with javafx and need to implement filters for my tablecolumns.

What I need is functionality to right click on column header and add a filter. I know I can have contextmenu added to my header which will be displayed when I right click my header but I don know how to open a new window (as in swing JFrame) create a filter according to datatype in column and filter data when filter is applied (auto closing this new window).

Comment: there (never tried) must be [Comparator for Table View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) a few times saw on this forum

Comment: @mKorbel my question is not about comparator I can write my own comparator but I need that right click part mainly.

Comment: but I need that right lick part mainly. – [for example](https://code.google.com/p/javafx-filterable-table-columns/)

Comment: already tried it but its not what I want, onclick it will open filter selection as shown...
I need a new window where I can select my filter click ok and then it will do filtering in my main window

Comment: I have do something like this. I have a tableView with some data, when I right click on the top a textfield apear and I can filter my data with a regex. and it's dynamicaly refresh. To do this I filter my stuff on my observableList and aplly my new ObservableList to the listView each time the filter is changed.

Comment: @agonist_ can you give example in a code

Comment: Panemu's [TwiulFX](http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/demo/) allows context menus to be used to set filters on columns.

Comment: @jewelsea I had one other question can you answer it here rather than me asking new question Thanks
am also trying to implement deleting elements(rows) from my table

I am using table.getItems().remove(index); but it is slow is there ny other way which is fatser

Comment: @jewelsea can same thing be replicated for tableheader am unable to do so...